# Interval ratio at stationary point of curve

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> Show that the curve $y=x^a(1-x)^b$ has a turning point whose
> x-coordinate divides the interval $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ in the ratio $a:b$

After taking the derivative of the curve and setting it equal to zero, I obtain $x=\frac{a}{a+b}$

Now I'm not sure what to do after, unless my $x$ coordinate is incorrect. The interval is of length $x=1$, so do I just sub $x=1$? That doesn't work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you are on the right track.

I will take notation $XY$ to mean distance from point $X$ to point $Y$.

Let $A(0,0)$ and $B(1,0)$.

You have found that the abscissa of $I$ is $\dfrac{a}{a+b}$; said otherwise:

$$AI=\dfrac{a}{a+b}.$$

Due to the fact that $AI+IB=AB=1$:

$$IB= 1-AI=1-\dfrac{a}{a+b}=\dfrac{b}{a+b}.$$

Finally, the distance ratio is

$$\dfrac{IA}{IB}=\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{a+b}}{\dfrac{b}{a+b}}=\dfrac{a}{b}$$

Comment: Thanks! TIL abscissa

Comment: what do you mean by complementary value?

Comment: oh I think it is the magnitude in the positive $x$ direction as opposed to towards the left

Comment: Said otherwise, it comes from the following equation between segment lengths: $AI+IB=AB=1 \implies IB=1-AI$